# Adding key name to value using jq

Tags: jq

I am trying to dynamically assign the key name as its value in my json

This is the json i am using:

```
{
    "test1": "",
    "test2": "",
    "test3": ""
}
```

the result i would like to obtain looks like this:

```
{
    "test1": "test1",
    "test2": "test2",
    "test3": "test3"
}
```

---

I am not familiar with jq and the closest result i got is using:

`keys[] as $key | {"\($key)": "\($key)"} | .`

here is the output:

```
{
  "test1": "test1"
}
{
  "test2": "test2"
}
{
  "test3": "test3"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`with_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) lets you manipulate `.key` and `.value` for each field. Just set one to the value of the other:

```bash
with_entries(.value = .key)
```

```json
{
  "test1": "test1",
  "test2": "test2",
  "test3": "test3"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Dd_LJAtXapz)

---

Following your approach, you could collect your result objects into an array using the [array constructors](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Arrayconstruction%3A%5B%5D) `[…]` around your filter, and then [`add`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#add) up the array's items producing one merged object. (Note that `| .` can be dropped as it doesn't do anything but [reproduce itself](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Identity%3A.), and that the [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29) `"\($key)"` is just the same as `$key`, given `$key` is a string, which is the case here as [object field names are always strings](https://www.json.org/).)

```bash
[keys[] as $key | {($key): $key}] | add
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7py6IasqC0g)

You may also entirely drop the use of variables as there is no other context interfering:

```bash
[keys[] | {"\(.)": .}] | add
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/H2ETH4VjsgA)

And there is a shortcut for patterns like `[.[] | …]` called [`map`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map%28x%29%2Cmap_values%28x%29):

```bash
keys | map({"\(.)": .}) | add
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EbXa7DcbUPz)

Alternatively, you also might want to consider using [`reduce`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce) for an iterative manipulation, and/or [`keys_unsorted`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#keys,keys_unsorted) which acts like `keys` but produces the keys in the original (unsorted) order:

```bash
reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key (.; .[$key] = $key)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UhQkIprBokm)

Comment: thank you for the explanation, i was imagining that i was just getting in more complicated logic to do some basic operation, this is exactly what i need